# Master/details flat file with FileHelpers in the same line

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I have a master-details flat file like this:

```
CSTRID NAME PHN1 EMAIL1  PHN2 EMAIL2 ...
01     Bill 3433 1@b.com 2333 2@b.com 
02     Jess 5555 3@b.com
```

(Each line is a customer. It may have 1 or more contact info fields)

Is there anyway to model this automatically with FileHelpers? Is there anyway I can have master and details in the same line? Maybe some kind of MultiRecord where the line separator may differ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use FileHelpers is to think of it as a way to describe the file format and (for the time being) to ignore the desired destination classes. Then after you've run the file through the FileHelpers engine, you can transform the resulting records in a separate step.

There is a standard name for moving data between systems: ETL which stands for [Extract, Transform, Load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load). If you like, FileHelpers is a good tool for the 'Extract' part of this.

So in your case, your FileHelpers class would look something like this:

```
[FixedLengthRecord()] 
public class MyFileHelpersClass
{
    [FieldFixedLength(5)] 
    public String Cstrid;
    [FieldFixedLength(10)] 
    public String Name;
    [FieldFixedLength(10)] 
    public String Phn1;
    [FieldFixedLength(20)] 
    public String Email1;
    [FieldFixedLength(10)] 
    public String Phn2;
    [FieldFixedLength(20)] 
    public String Email2;
    // etc.
}
```

Then you import it to an array of `MyFileHelpersClass[]` with

```
MyFileHelpersClass[] res = engine.ReadFile("FileIn.txt") as MyFileHelpersClass[];
```

Then you transform and load these results as a second step, something like

```
foreach (MyFileHelpersSpec result in results)
{
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.Name = result.Name;
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Phn1) 
        || !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email1))
    {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.Phone = result.Phn1;
        contact.Email = result.Email1;
        customer.Contacts.Add(contact);
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Phn2)
        || !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email2))
    {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.Phone = result.Phn2;
        contact.Email = result.Email2;
        customer.Contacts.Add(contact);
    }               
}
```

You can often use LINQ if your transform logic is very basic, something like

```
var customers = results
    .Where(x => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Phn1))
    .Select(x => new Customer() { Name = x.Name, Phone = x.Phn1 })
    .Union(
        results
        .Where(x => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Phn2))
        .Select(x => new Customer() { Name = x.Name, Phone = x.Phn2 })
    );
```

Comment: Sorry but you missed the point. I don't know beforehand how many contact info fields there will be in one line. Quoting the question: " It may have 1 or more contact info fields" I do know that I must focus on the file structure, not the desired output classes. Anyway, I've come up mentally with a neat solution, that I will code and share tomorrow, being that the nice thing to do.